# validation issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to Jquery and have used an asp.net form in which I have 3 textboxes and 1 button. My code is working but there is a problem that not all of my validations  are working at the same time. Example: I leave username text box and entered password and password again its showing me only 1 textbox error.

My Java Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
       $("#<%=style2.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            var valid = false
            errorMessage = ""
            var pass = $("#<%=textbox4.ClientID%>").val();
            var pass1 = $("#<%=textbox5.ClientID%>").val();
            if ($("#<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").val() == '') {
                errorMessage = "please enter your name \n"
                valid = true
            }

            else if (pass != pass1) {
                errorMessage = "password not match"
                valid = true
            }
            if (valid==true) {
                alert(errorMessage)
                return false
            }

        });
       $("#<%=textbox4.ClientID%>").keypress(function () {
           $("#<%=Label1.ClientID %>").text(countlength($("#<%=textbox4.ClientID%>").val()))
          function countlength(len) {
              var count = 0
              if (len.length < 8) {
                  return "Chracters Atleast 8"
              }
              else {
                  return "Strong Password"
              }
          }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you write error message as alert. If you want check all fields and then open one error message, you should assign checks on submit button and open one pop-up when all fields are filled and user wants submit form.

Other way is check each field separately and open not pop-up, but for example div with error message right under the input field after the field value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

// Remove 'else' from your 'if-else' statement and concatenate error message with '+' sign

```
    $("#<%=style2.ClientID%>").click(function () 
    {
            var valid = false
            errorMessage = ""
            var pass = $("#<%=textbox4.ClientID%>").val();
            var pass1 = $("#<%=textbox5.ClientID%>").val();
            if ($("#<%=textbox1.ClientID%>").val() == '') {
                errorMessage = "please enter your name \n"
                valid = true
            }

            //Remove else
            if (pass != pass1) {
            //concatenate error message
                errorMessage += "password not match"
                valid = true
            }
            if (valid==true) {
                alert(errorMessage)
                return false
            }

     });
```

hope this will work.